# Should I start making apps with Xcode 6 or 5.1?

Tags: xcode

I was starting to make simple iPhone apps using online tutorials and books and then I realized that I upgraded to OS X Yosemite and can only download Xcode 6.1 and all the tutorials are based on Xcode 5.1. I can't learn anything with Xcode 6 since there aren't many tutorials out there for Xcode 6. Can someone please suggest me what to do? basically I'm trying to learn objective-c but before learning objective-c I'd like to make a simple app through tutorials and get the hang of Xcode and learn further..

Comment: Always use the latest tools for iOS or OS X development. Apple only moves forward.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry, proceed with the current version.  Any differences will be made obvious by compiler warnings or errors, at which point you can deal with them.  This might be considered preferable to learning to do something in a manner which is no longer current